# Matrices always permute a vector space basis?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

Is it possible that given any matrix in $GL_n(K)$ (with $K$ a field) where the selected matrix has finite order, one can show a basis that is permutated by the transformation made by the selected matrix?

For example. Consider the matrix

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
It is well known that this matrix switches the basis $(1\ 0)^T$ and $(0\ 1)^T$ to the other. 
But, for the matrix
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1 \\
 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
 Is this possible? (The question is made for any finite dimension, this is only an example).

Comment: I don't think is true in general you, you would want to put any matrix into a permutation matrix, so for example you would need $A^n=id$ for some $n$, so if you take any scalar matrix $\lambda id$ this is not true.

Comment: Oh, you're right, maybe is a good idea don't add restrictions to the dimension.

Comment: But, if the matrix has finite order is possible?

Comment: Still think no, for example take $\mathbb R^2$ and the rotation by $\pi/4$ this does not fix any pair of lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. For a given matrix $A$ and a matrix $S$ representing the change to the new basis, $S^{-1}AS$ would need to be a permutation matrix, and $\det S^{-1}AS=\det A$. The determinant of a permutation matrix is $\pm1$, whereas the restriction that $A$ be of finite order only constrains the determinant to be some root of unity.